# Program executed using QProcess fails to start

Tags: qt, pyqt, qprocess

I'm trying to execute a process using `QProcess` on Windows, but it keeps failing to start.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
env = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()

proc = QtCore.QProcess()
proc.setProcessEnvironment(env)

proc.start('chef-solo --version') # works on command line
# proc.start('\\opscode\\chef\\bin\\chef-solo --version') # works on command line
# proc.start('c:\\opscode\\chef\\bin\\chef-solo --version') # works on command line
# proc.start('chef-solo', '--version') # doesn't work (no command line analog)
# proc.start('chef-solo', ['--version']) # doesn't work (no command line analog)
# proc.start('ping www.google.com') # works!

if not proc.waitForStarted():
    print "didn't start", proc.error()
```

This invariably prints `didn't start 0`.  `proc.error()` is `0`, `proc.readAllStandardError()` and `proc.readAllStandardOutput()` are empty.  The `PATH` variable is set correctly in `env`, and besides I'm specifying the full path to the program.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried 
proc.start('chef-solo', '--version') ?

Comment: Yes.  Modified the example to show that.

Comment: Chris, have you tried to check for errors? Stdout/err, errorString? Can you execute the same process with subprocess.call and its subvariants?

Comment: So what error does it give? Also, why do you use the `env`?

Comment: There are no errors to stdout/stderr, and the error it gives is 0 "FailedToStart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, there's both a `chef-solo` *and* a `chef-solo.bat` in the chef directory.  Running `chef-solo` on the command line executes `chef-solo.bat`.  This doesn't work through `QProcess`, where you have to explicitly list `chef-solo.bat` in order for it to run the program.

Comment: Gosh! It would have been simpler if you had elaborated more about the error you were facing. ;-)